# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I am stuck with this error. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong (img is an image with 3 rgb channels and conversion_array is a 3x3 array).

```
conversion_array = np.array([[1,0,1.402],[1,-0.344136,-0.714136],[1,1.772,0]], dtype = float)

def encoder_ex5(img):
    new_img = np.zeros(shape = (len(img),len(img[0]), 3 ), dtype = float)
    for j in range(len(img)):
        for k in range(len(img[0])):
            new_img[j][k] =  np.multiply(conversion_array , img[j][k])

    return new_img



img = plt.imread('plant.bmp')
img2 = encoder_ex5(img)
```

The error shown is the one in the title. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no line or statement in the code in which the `encoder_ex5` is called. Try showing the whole code in which the `encoder_ex5` is called.

Comment: Changed it. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct function for this case is np.dot not np.multiply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Where's the error?  Traceback?

`conversion_array` is (3,3) shape, right?

What's the shape of `img`?  2d, 3d?   `img[j][k]` is better written as `img[j,k]`.  But what's its shape?

`new_img` is 3d by construction, so `new_img[j,k]` has shape (3,), right?

Did you check the shape of: `np.multiply(conversion_array , img[j,k])`?  The error says it's (3,3).  Do you understand why?  You are doing

`conversion_array*img[j,k]`, a (3,3) times a (3,) or scalar, in either case a (3,3).  You can't put that in a (3,) slot!

What do you want to do?  The other answer suggests using `np.dot`, matrix multiplication, which with a (3,3) and (3,) would give a (3,).